# Configure Restangular.baseUrl using Gruntjs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, restangular

I'm using Restangular in a project built using Gruntjs. Here is a snippet:

```
// scripts/app.js

angular.module('myApp', ['restangular'])])
  .config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider) {

    /* this is different on dev, test, prod environments */
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/sms-api/rest/management/';

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(baseUrl);
}])
```

I would like to have a different value for `baseUrl` if specified at cli or a default if not specified:

```
$ grunt server
Using default value for 'baseUrl'

$ grunt build --rest.baseUrl='http://my.domain.com/rest/management/'
Using 'http://my.domain.com/rest/management/' for 'baseUrl'
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible with the aid of [Grunt preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) which is useful for replacing (and other things) templates inside files.

First add this to your **.js** code:

```
/* Begin insertion of baseUrl by GruntJs */
/* @ifdef baseUrl
 var baseUrl = /* @echo baseUrl */ // @echo ";"
 // @endif */

/* @ifndef baseUrl
 var baseUrl = 'http://www.fallback.url';
 // @endif */
/* End of baseUrl insertion */
```

Then in your grunt file, after installing grunt preprocess (i.e `npm install grunt-preprocess --save-dev` you add the following configuration:

```
 preprocess: {
        options: {
            context: {

            }
        },
        js: {
            src: 'public/js/services.js',
            dest: 'services.js'
        }
    },
```

**obviously**, you need to update the js file list accordingly to which ever files you use. **important** notice - if you are planning on updating the same file (and not to a new destination) you need to use the **inline option**

At last, in order to work with a `command line config variable`, add the following custom task to your grunt file as well:

```
grunt.registerTask('baseUrl', function () {
        var target = grunt.option('rest.baseUrl') || undefined;
        grunt.log.ok('baseUrl is set to', target);
        grunt.config('preprocess.options.context.baseUrl', target);
        grunt.task.run('preprocess');
    });
```

Finally, run the baseUrl task like so:

```
grunt baseUrl --rest.baseUrl='http://some.domain.net/public/whatever'
```

*Notice I put in a fallback url so you can also run `grunt baseUrl` and grunt will set your baseUrl to your defined one.*

Comment: the insertion to the .js file is more complex than it should be because I don't like Jetbrains to then alert me about all sorts of unnecessary stuff (like semi-colon or whatever). Also @echo has had some issues for me, so I manually output the closing ; *semi-colon*